# Python. PyCharm. Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, pycharm

работаю в Pycharm.
Скрипт стал завершаться:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Я попытался запустить скрипт через CMD, но там программа просто останавливалась.

Как решить данную проблему и с чем она связана?
Python из Anaconda

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема в IDE, а не в скрипте?

Comment: @cppquestions Ну либо в самом Python, либо в PyCharm.